# ms sql xml data type convert to text

Tags: sql-server, xml, delphi, text, delphi-7

in MS Sql there are data types that are not supported by delphi 7, the xml datatype is one example.

I wish to convert the XML datatype to Text datatype, so that i could handle it in delphi.

Is there a way to convert from xml to text?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

A simple cast will suffice:

```
select cast(XMLCol as nvarchar(max)) as XMLCol
```

Or for non-unicode:

```
select cast(XMLCol as varchar(max)) as XMLCol
```

You can't convert explicitly to a 'text' data type.

I've added the `as XMLCol` to ensure that the converted data has the the same name as the column. You needn't have this, of course.

**EDIT:**

A few links. You are encouraged to use nvarchar(max) instead of `text` regardless. Microsoft have said they will be deprecating these types in future releases.  nvarchar(max) ought to offer you 2GB:

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/734.cfm

http://www.teratrax.com/articles/varchar_max.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: the problem with varchar is the limit of x bytes, which is not the case for xml.

Comment: Which version of SQL Are you using. nvarchar(max) should offer you up to 2GB.

Comment: after a quick search , there is a difference between specifying varchar(5000) and varchar(max)

Comment: Neither CAST() or CONVERT() will properly unescape the xml. The handling of converting to a NULL when there's no matching tag on a nodeset query function also fails.

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT CAST(YourXMLColumn as nvarchar(max))
    FROM YourTable
```

Comment: This is what I normally do, it's so clean, easy to remember, hard to mess up :)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the follwing solution and yes, you do need the `as XMLCol`

```
select cast(XMLCol as nvarchar(max)) as XMLCol
```